# UICollectionViewFlowLayout edge cells disappear when translation transform is applied

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to make cells zoom and fade as they reach the top. To do this, I'm applying an `alpha` and `transform` to the layout attributes. Here's my code ([link to full demo repo](https://github.com/aheze/TransitioningCollectionLayout/tree/CustomLayout)):

```
class EdgeZoomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }
        let rectAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }
        let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.frame.size)

        for attributes in rectAttributes where attributes.frame.intersects(visibleRect) {
            let positionInFrameY = attributes.center.y - visibleRect.origin.y /// y origin of rectangle
            let cutoff = CGFloat(30)
            
            if positionInFrameY <= cutoff {
                let translation = cutoff - positionInFrameY /// distance from the cutoff, 0 if exactly on cutoff
                let alpha = 1 - (translation / 100)
                let scale = 1 - (translation / 1000)
                
                attributes.alpha = alpha
                attributes.zIndex = Int(alpha >= 1 ? 1 : 0) /// if alpha is 1, keep on the top
                attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale).translatedBy(x: 0, y: translation)
            } else {
                attributes.zIndex = 1 /// keep on top if not getting zoomed
            }
        }

        return rectAttributes
    }

    /// boilerplate code
    override init() { super.init() }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool { return true }
    override func invalidationContext(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
        let context = super.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds) as! UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext
        context.invalidateFlowLayoutDelegateMetrics = newBounds.size != collectionView?.bounds.size
        return context
    }
}
```

This is almost perfect, but the topmost cell disappears suddenly when it gets close to the edge:

[image: Top cell disappears when it reached the top]

How can I make the cell zoom and fade without vanishing like that? I think it might be because the collection view recycled the cell... but then, how do I keep it?

Comment: Have you tried using `(translation / 100)` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can remove this line

```
where attributes.frame.intersects(visibleRect)
```

or you can add some point for `visibleRect` by this

```
for attributes in rectAttributes where attributes.frame.intersects(visibleRect.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -15)) {
```

Comment: I think it is still the same issue. Try scolling slower. You see that the top most cell drops.

Comment: @mahan just adjust dy value and I think where the condition is not required.