# How to fade collection view cells as user scrolls?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

What I want to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQZmI.jpg

What I attempted to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR4kb.jpg

As the user scrolls, I want some UI elements on the cell to fade away and appear again depending on scroll position.

What I tried is:

```
func fadeCell(for indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let screenHalf = collectionView.bounds.height / 2 + collectionView.bounds.height * CGFloat(indexPath.row)
  let topPosition = collectionView.contentOffset.y
  guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SomeCellClass,
    topPosition >= 0 else { return }
  let needOpacityToZeroChange = topPosition >= screenHalf
  let opacity = needOpacityToZeroChange ? 0 : 1 - ((topPosition.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: screenHalf)) / screenHalf)
  cell.fade(with: opacity)
}
```

**SomeCellClass** is a UICollectionViewCell used for given collectionView.

**cell.fade()** is a method of SomeCellClass which sets alpha of certain UIViews to given opacity.

**fadeCell(for indexPath: IndexPath)** would be called in UICollectionViewDelegate's **didScroll()** method for visible cells on the screen.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68087902/14351818

Comment: I would recommend a custom flow layout. A bit complicated, but very powerful. And the one I linked above is only ~30 lines long.